# Add custom word in the URL of Route attribute ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

How to add a custom, user defined word in the URL of some MVC call?

For example I have this attribute on my controller's method:

```
[Route("accounts/transactions"]
```

What I'm trying to do is to change that route into this form: `/accounts/{accountNumber}/transactions`

Where accountNumber is changeable and send by client in the moment when request is send. Client send his account number via URL like this: `localhost:50490/accounts/1234567890/transactions` and controller method gets invoked.

Can I change Route parameter somehow so it can handle this situation or I need completely different solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can change the route to handle this situation.

**Solution 1:**

```
 [Route("accounts/{accountNumber:int}/transactions"]
 public ActionResult Transactions(int accountNumber) {
     /* action body */
 }
```

**Notes:**

1) `accountNumber:int` is just for integer and don't allow null.

2) Your action must have `accountNumber` as parameter.

---

**Solution 2:**
You can add this route in `RouteConfig`

```
 routes.MapRoute(
      name: "accountNumber",
      url: "accounts/{accountNumber}/transactions",
      defaults: new { controller = "Accounts", action = "Transactions" }
 );
```

Your *Action* must take that as a parameter

```
 public ActionResult Transactions(string accountNumber) {
     /* action body */
 }
```

Comment: thanks for answer, one more question: so passing int into method (or string) is must in all cases, right? @adricadar

Comment: Yes, it's required in all cases, to accept null you must add in Solution1 `{accountNumber?}` and in Solution2, in `defaults`, you add `accountNumber = UrlParameter.Optional`